# How to trigger 'change' on <input> changed programmatically

Tags: vue.js

I'm going to build a customized virtual keyboard, so that's the first problem I've encountered.
I have an `input` element, whose value is changed from outside, in my case by pressing a button. The problem is that there seems to be no way to trigger the normal `'change'` event.

Neither clicking outside the `input`, nor pressing Enter gives any result.

What might be the correct way of solving this problem?

```js
<template>
  <div class="app-input">
    <input @change="onChange" type="text" v-model="value" ref="input">
    <button @click="onClick">A</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "AppInput",
  data() {
    return {
      inputDiv: null,
      value: ""
    };
  },
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  methods: {
    onClick() {
      this.value = this.value + "A";
      this.inputDiv.focus();
    },
    onChange() {
      alert("changed");
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.inputDiv = this.$refs.input;
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

The whole pen can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-e00rp).

Answer (score 6):

`v-on:change` would only trigger on a direct change on the input element from a user action.

What you are looking for is a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) for your data property, whenever your `value` changes, watcher will execute your desired function or task.

```
watch: {
  value: function() {
    this.onChange();
  }
}
```

The `watch` syntax is elaborated on the provided official vuejs docs link. Use your data property as the key and provide a function as a value.

Check the snippet:

```js
export default {
  name: "AppInput",
  data() {
    return {
      inputDiv: null,
      value: ""
    };
  },
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  methods: {
    onClick() {
      this.value = this.value + "A";
      this.inputDiv.focus();
    },
    onChange() {
      alert("changed");
    }
  },
  // this one:
  watch: {
    value: function() {
      this.onChange();
    }
  },
  // --- rest of your code;
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.inputDiv = this.$refs.input;
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: The problem is that if it triggers `onChange` on every value change (which will be with the `watch`er) this is not how the vanilla `input` works.

Comment: the event you are talking about is the `change` event, it usually works like when you type something and the `input` element loses focus, and if there is any change the event triggers, but when you are choosing to click on the custom button, your input element already lost focus, I am not sure how else you can capture the change, or how do you know user has done changing since they are not providing inputs from the keyboard, and your input element lost focus, and you are manually focusing it each time

Comment: I understand this, that's why I'm wondering, what could be the solution...

Comment: what is it exactly are you trying to execute on each `change` ? I mean for now it's an alert only, I understand an alert after each key type is disturbing (I presume it's for testing only) but depending on your requirement, there could be another way.

Comment: I'd like it to work as close as possible to an ordinary input, where we have the `change` event on focus blur, enter etc. Not on addition of a letter.

Comment: @EugeneBarsky Every time the user presses the button the input's blur event would fire

Comment: @EugeneBarsky Then you should realize why these 2 statements cannot coexist:  "The problem is that if it triggers onChange on every value change"  -  "I'd like it to work as close as possible to an ordinary input, where we have the change event on focus blur, enter etc. Not on addition of a letter".  It can't be both ways.

Comment: @Dan What would be the best solution?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. You can either do some processing after every letter change or choose another event to process from, like Enter keypress. It's just that change probably isn't an option because the input is blurred on every virtual button press, and blur triggers change if there has been some typing too.  (Can the user type too with the actual keyboard?)  If you must use the `change` event, the best way is probably to make a custom input wrapper component and `emit` the `change` whenever you want.

Comment: @Dan I've managed not to lose focus when clicking the button, so now I'm thinking about how to emulate the same behaviour as with vanilla input.

Comment: And yes, the user can type with the actual keyboard as well.

Answer (score 1):

When I build any new vue application, I like to use these events for a search input or for other inputs where I don't want to fire any functions on `@change`

```html
<div class="class">
   <input v-model="searchText" @keyup.esc="clearAll()" @keyup.enter="getData()" autofocus type="text" placeholder="Start Typing ..."/>
   <button @click="getData()"><i class="fas fa-search fa-lg"></i></button>
</div>
```

These will provide a better user experience in my opinion.